# Pass None or empty value to dictionary key if result from result comprehension is nothing

Tags: list-comprehension, python-2.6, dictionary-comprehension

How to pass None or empty value to `failure_dict['Failure Reason']` if failure reason has no value.

```
failure_dict['Failure Reason'] = ', '.join(
            [failure_reason for failure_reason in self.get_failure_reason(summary_content) if failure_reason])
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want the list in `join()` to contain an empty value if `self.get_failure_reason` returns an empty value. You can't have `None` since `join()` will only work with a list of strings. For that:

```py
failure_dict['Failure Reason'] = ', '.join(
            [failure_reason for failure_reason in self.get_failure_reason(summary_content)
             if failure_reason else ''])
```

If what you want to do is give `failure_dict['Failure Reason']` a `None` value if *any* of the return values of `self.get_failure_reason` is empty, you'll have to open up the for loop:

```py
return_list = []
flag = 1
for failure_reason in self.get_failure_reason(summary_content):
    if failure_reason:
        return_list.append(failure_reason)
    else:
        flag = 0
        break

if flag:
    failure_dict['Failure Reason'] = ', '.join(return_list)
else:
    failure_dict['Failure Reason'] = None
```